# Tag-Score on android-studio tag is not increasing despite votes

Tags: support, up-votes, tag-score

Up votes on my answer under the [android-studio](/questions/tagged/android-studio) tag in Stack Overflow are stuck at 99 from last week. I am getting 5-7 upvotes daily on my answers under this tag but the same is not reflecting neither on top-users section of that tag nor on tags section in profile. It is stuck at 99.

Is it expected behavior or is something wrong?

Comment: Today morning it got resolved.